# Configure Serilog in .NET 6 Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor-pages, serilog

I have a web progressive app based on razor pages (.net 6) and I cant configure serilog by file in my project.

My program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Logging.AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Serilog")).AddSerilog();
```

My .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="4.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

My appsettings.json

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/webapi-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3}] {Username} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm injecting the log on my razor pages like:

```
@inject ILogger<Edit> _logger
```

The logs are not written to the log file I configured.

Comment: I just updated the error message @mason

Answer (score 0):

You pass `ConfigurationSection` instead of `IConfiguration` - there is no overloading method, which accepts parameter like that. I guess you should pass `builder.Configuration` instead:

```cs
builder.Logging.AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration);
```

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: try `.AddConfiguration(builder, builder.configuration)`

Comment: it does not work. the problem is that does not know the method AddConfiguration

Comment: it sees extension method as error says, so it doesn't look like there is no method...

Answer (score 0):

Add nuget package -

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration
```

and use below namespace in `Program.cs` file -

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

That should fix the `ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddConfiguration'` error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed the error with your suggestion, but nothing is written to the log file. I updated my question with your inputs.